# Open all file types with Default OS program

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, external

Is there a way to link  to open all file extensions with default OS program instead of internal to Electron?

My file names are loaded from JSON file. (Value.url IS the file name pulled in dynamically during a search)

I modified my code below to link the click event to the openBtnId, but now i'm receivING "electron is not defined".  I have const shell = require('electron').shell; in my mainJS.

```
function renderHTML(data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $('#aceCategory').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        htmlString += "<p class='categoryName'>" + data[i].category + "</p>" + "<tr>" + "<td class='feedDesc'>" + "<b>" + data[i].name +
            "</b>" + "<br>" + data[i].desc + "</br>" + "<br>" + "<input type='button' id='openBtn' style='border-radius: 25px; outline: none' value='Open Link'  >" + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";

    }
    aceFeedTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString)
    $(document).on("click", "#openBtn", function() {
        electron.shell.openItem(data[i].url);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set nodeIntegration to true and added  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');  to my mainWindow html. and now it recognizes shell.openItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shell.openItem(fullPath)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenitemfullpath) for that.

```
const {shell} = require("electron");
shell.openItem("/path/to/my/file");
```

This has to be done either in the main process or in a BrowserWindow that has `nodeIntegration` set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks @snwflk, but doesn't that require me to hard code the file path?  My script uses JSON to write the html dynamically as I search and then I click the button to open the file.  The file names changes depending on the search, but they're all tied to the input button.

Comment: This is just an example usage, of course you can use variables instead of the string literal. Also, please try to keep the question in the original form and ask new questions for new problems that arise later.

Comment: I removed the "onclick" from the input button and added this function, but is says electron not defined..  I'd greatly appreciate an example because I'm not sure what i'm missing.  Thanks!
        $(document).on("click", "#openBtn", function() {
            Electron.shell.openItem(data[i].url);

Comment: Just to be sure, it says "electron is not defined" ? And not "require is not defined" ?

Comment: I set nodeIntegration to true and added  <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    </script> to my mainWindow html.   and now it recognizes shell.openItem, but when it opens the file up in Google Earth it locks up my app with a popup that says files is being used by another appliction...

Comment: I feel that this is out of the scope of this question, which you've already changed substantially. Please research this separately and if you cannot find a solution, post this as a *new StackOverflow question*. Also, if you've found an answer helpful, consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: I haven’t changed my question substantially.  I included more of the script because I thought it would be helpful.  I do however, agree that through troubleshooting have moved on to separate issues.

Comment: Yes, you have: in the original question, you weren't using `openItem`. You then included that and moved on to other problems that arose from that. The original question had been answered since then. The idea on StackOverflow is to have a clear Question-Answer pattern, where the questions don't "shift". They aren't just about an individual's programming problem – they should be helpful for other people, too. Therefore it makes sense to preserve the question's original intent.